# Laravel: complex Many to Many Polymorphic Relationship for conditions and actions

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphic-associations

The **`Method`** model is a container of **conditions** (triggers) and **actions**.

- A `Method` has multiple `Condition`
- Each `Condition` has multiple `Action`

---

We can have different types of `Condition`, for instance:

- **Order amount** between `0` and `500` USD
- **Order weight** between `10` and `100` pounds

And we can have different types of `Action`, for instance:

- Call supervisor ID `5`
- Send email to `email@email.com`

---

[image]

We are creating a table for each type of `condition` and a table for each type of `action`. That way we don't end up with a table full of columns to encompass each possible scenario.

The problem is: how to create this Polymorphic Relationship?

---

Starting with `Conditions`…

My database looks like:

###### conditions

| id | condition_id | condition_type | method_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 5005 | App\Model\ConditionTypeOrderAmount | 1 |
| 1002 | 6006 | App\Model\ConditionTypeOrderWeight | 1 |

###### condition_type_order_amount

| id | min_amount | max_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5005 | 0 | 500 |

###### condition_type_order_weight

| id | min_weight | max_weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6006 | 10 | 100 |

###### actions

| id | action_id | action_type | condition_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8008 | 2002 | App\Models\ActionTypeCallSupervisor | 1001 |
| 8009 | 2002 | App\Models\ActionTypeCallSupervisor | 1002 |

###### action_type_call_supervisor

| id | supervisor_id | call_anytime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2002 | 5 | 1 |

---

I could partially achieve what I need using `belongsToMany` and `wherePivot` in `Method`, like:

```php
class Method extends Model
{
    public function orderAmountConditions()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(
                ConditionTypeOrderAmount::class,
                'conditions',
                'method_id',
                'condition_id',
            )->wherePivot(
                'condition_type',
                ConditionTypeOrderAmount::class
            );
    }

    public function orderWeightConditions()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(
                ConditionTypeOrderWeight::class,
                'conditions',
                'method_id',
                'condition_id',
            )->wherePivot(
                'condition_type',
                ConditionTypeOrderWeight::class
            );
    }
}
```

But in that scenario `conditions` table was used just as a pivot table and I had a single function for every type of condition. Not ideal.

So I tried to use Polymorphic Relationships, but than thing got confusing…

What I tried:

Both `ConditionTypeOrderAmount` and `ConditionTypeOrderWeight` have the same `conditions()` relationship:

```php
class ConditionTypeOrderAmount extends Model
{
    public function conditions()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(
            Condition::class,
            'conditions'
        );
    }
}
```

And `Condition` has:

```php
class Condition extends MorphPivot
{
    public function conditionable()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(
            Condition::class,
            'conditions',
            'condition_id',
        );
    }
}
```

But no results are found. I already read Laravel docs several times and watched a lot of YouTube videos, but I can't figure Polymorphic relationships.

Expected response would be something like:

```json
{
  "method": {
    "id": 1,
    "conditions": [
      {
        "id": 1001,
        "type": "App\Models\ConditionalTypeOrderAmount",
        "min_amount": 0,
        "max_amount": 500,
        "actions": [
          {
            "id": 8008,
            "type": "App\Models\ActionTypeCallSupervisor",
            "supervisor_id": 5,
            "call_anytime": 1,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 1002,
        "type": "App\Models\ConditionalTypeOrderWeight",
        "min_weight": 10,
        "max_weight": 100,
        "actions": [
          {
            "id": 8009,
            "type": "App\Models\ActionTypeCallSupervisor",
            "supervisor_id": 5,
            "call_anytime": 1,
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you overcomplicated. Use only `Model` to exdends from. See my answer bellow.

Comment: Do you solved this?

Comment: @LucianDex Thanks for your help. After a lot of thinking I realized that —as you said— I was overcomplicating things. I ended with an architecture very similar to what you presented, but now both Condition and Action _belongsTo_ method. I also extended only `Model`, as your suggestion.

Comment: The belongsTo in Action model was not provided in the schema presented above :).
I think you put method_id inside Action model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Condition` model (extends Model):

```php
    public function conditionable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function method()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(
            Method::class
        );
    }

    public function actions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(
            Action::class
        );
    }
```

In `ConditionType....` models (extends Model):

```php
    public function conditions()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(
            Condition::class,
            'conditionable',
        );
    }
```

In `Method` model (extends Model):

```php
    public function conditions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(
            Condition::class
        );
    }
```

In `Action` model (extends Model):

```php
    public function actionable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function condition()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(
            Condition::class
        );
    }
```

In `ActionType....` models (extends Model):

```php
    public function actions()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(
            Action::class,
            'actionable',
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve the problem, but I would start solving the problem by extracting sql of this data itself. If you manage to format the data correctly, you will probably fix the problem yourself

```sql
select
    i.id,
    i.condition_type,
    ct.min_amount,
    ct.max_amount,
    atc.supervisor_id,
    atc.call_anytime
from
    conditions i
    left join condition_type_order_amount ct on i.condition_id = ct.id
    left join actions a on i.id = a.condition_id
    left join action_type_call_supervisor atc on a.action_id = atc.id
where
    i.condition_type = 'ConditionalTypeOrderAmount';
```